# Spring Security basic configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, configuration

I would like to configure spring MVC application using Spring security the following way.

1. Only one concurrent login allowed.
2. When HTTP session expires the user will be redirected to /security/sessionTimeout.html
3. when user logs in on success he will be redirected to "/" folder.
4. When users logs out, he will be redirected to "/" as well.

I configured it the following way:

```
   <security:http>
 <security:form-login login-page="/security/login.html" login-processing-url="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1" default-target-url="/"/> 
  <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/security/sessionTimeout.html">
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
    </security:session-management>
  <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/>
    </security:http>
```

and I have the following issues:

1. I'm able to login with the same account on 2 different browsers (no concurrency control is working)
2. when I click on log out I got redirected to "/security/sessionTimeout.html" instead of "/".

I've followed Spring security reference guide.
What am I doing wrong?

**Updated:**
This is how my web.xml looks like.

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/springSecurity-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
 <display-name>SpringSecurity</display-name>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springSecurity</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springSecurity</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springSecurity</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springSecurity</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

**Update 2**:
just run log4j in debug mode and this is what I got when clicking on logout:

```
DEBUG [http-8080-2] (FilterChainProxy.java:375) - /index.html at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter'
DEBUG [http-8080-2] (FilterChainProxy.java:375) - /index.html at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG [http-8080-2] (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:130) - No HttpSession currently exists
    DEBUG [http-8080-2] (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:88) - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
    DEBUG [http-8080-2] (FilterChainProxy.java:375) - /index.html at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
    DEBUG [http-8080-2] (FilterChainProxy.java:375) - /index.html at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
    DEBUG [http-8080-2] (FilterChainProxy.java:375) - /index.html at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
    DEBUG [http-8080-2] (FilterChainProxy.java:375) - /index.html at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
    DEBUG [http-8080-2] (FilterChainProxy.java:375) - /index.html at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
    DEBUG [http-8080-2] (FilterChainProxy.java:375) - /index.html at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
    DEBUG [http-8080-2] (AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:67) - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
    DEBUG [http-8080-2] (FilterChainProxy.java:375) - /index.html at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
    DEBUG [http-8080-2] (SessionManagementFilter.java:87) - Requested session IDD8429BBAAA9561A97E1D2350ED63BC35 is invalid.
    DEBUG [http-8080-2] (SessionManagementFilter.java:90) - Starting new session (if required) and redirecting to '/security/sessionTimeout.html'
```

it feels like I have session managment filter applied on `/index.html` and then no session exists. how can I solve it?

Comment: the item b) is happening probably because you didn't allowed the url `/` to be accessed by any user.

Comment: which spring version are you using ?

Comment: @Simeon, 3.0.5 and Spring 3.0.4

Comment: Bluefoot is probably right. Have you tried changing the `<servlet-mapping>` just to include `*` and see if the behavior is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Spring Security documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html):

To use concurrent session support, you'll need to add the following to web.xml:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
    org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Did you add this?

Comment: It looks like I have it, but I posted my entire web.xml configuration in update.